# Is there an equivalent for @react-navigation/native but for React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, libraries

I want to use `useIsFocused` hook but I am running a `React.js` project, not a `React Native`.

Is there a library that gives me the same but for `React.js` or is there any way I can make a `useEffect` run every time the page gets focused?

Answer (score 0):

useEffect hook run every time the page gets focused in a React application, you can use the window object's focus and blur events in conjunction with the useEffect

Comment: This is not happening to me, every time I navigate to another route and then I come back, the `useEffect` is not triggered although the focus is on that page.